# Wordpress login_redirect filter gets ignored and has no effect

Tags: wordpress, filter

I'm trying to send users with a specific meta tag to a special page when they log in. I know the $current_user global may not be available, but that the filter passes the user as a parameter, so I think what I'm doing should work:

```
//special login redirect for employers
function employer_login_redirect($redirect_url, $request_url, $user) {
    $user;
    $is_employer = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'is_employer', true);
    var_dump($is_employer);
    if ($is_employer) {
        return get_bloginfo('url') . "/candidate-ranks/";
    } else {
        return $redirect_url;
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'employer_login_redirect', 90, 3 ); //late priority just in case other plugins are interfering
```

Am I missing something? I can't even get the var_dumpt to show up, which makes me think the callback function isn't even getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine but I think you should use `site_url()` because`get_bloginfo('url')` returns home_url not the site_url. This could be a problrm.

```
function employer_login_redirect($redirect_url, $request_url, $user) {
    $is_employer = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'is_employer', true);
    if ($is_employer) {
        return site_url() . "/candidate-ranks/";
    } else {
        return $redirect_url;
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'employer_login_redirect', 90, 3 );
```

Comment: I'll definitely give that a try. But I'm worried that the filter isn't working at all bc the var_dump() isn't showing up. Should I expect to see that regardless of the redirect URL?

Comment: What do you see after login and make sure whether it's being called or not by placing `var_dump($is_employer);exit` inside that function before any return.

Comment: I added the ...exit; and nothing happens. I just get the homepage, as usual. The filter must not be working, but I can't see why.

Comment: try changing the `priority` to `10` and see what happens ?

Comment: [Also check the manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect).

Comment: Nothing happens with priority 10 either. I started with the manual but I can't see anything I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It's wired, nothing wrong with your code but may be you can check if any plugin making this to happen so disable all plugins ans re-enable them one by one and see which one is the culprit.

Comment: Bingo. I'm using s2Member plugin. When I deactivate it the redirect works as planned. This is great that I know the problem. But I wonder if there's any way around it... because I need that plugin. Changing the priority didn't seem to have any effect. Do you know of an earlier hook/filter that s2Member might be using?

Comment: Look up in the plugin's core files what hook is being used and what the priority is and then also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539947/how-can-i-change-action-priority-in-wordpress/12540186#12540186) of mine.