# Hook actions from plugins in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to rearrange some items on my WooCommerce product page.
I know how to do this for the most built-in items/actions in WooCommerce like the product title for example.

To do this, I remove the action and add a new one with. Like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5, 0);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary_header', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5, 0);
```

To find the action hooks I look in the theme file or I'm using the plugin "Simply Show Hooks" (https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/simply-show-hooks/).

If I want to rearrange actions from thrid party plugins, I often find different looking hooks. Like this one:

```
WC_Wishlists_Plugin–>add_to_wishlist_button
```

How could I remove such action hooks and add the in a new position?
The way from above doesn't work for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539947/how-can-i-change-action-priority-in-wordpress, I hope this helps?

Comment: not really. or I don't understand it :-/

Comment: And the plugin they mention in the second answer? :)

Comment: that's not working for me because I want to display the actions on completely different places, prioritizing wouldn't help.